# Sorting an array doesn't take the first element to compare(java programming)?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array that include 5 numbers(size=4) from largest to smallest, but I spend a long time and I don't know why my code don't take the first element to be sorted..

This is My code:

```
public class sortingS
{
public static void main(String []args)
{
    int a[]={5,-2,10,14,-1};
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            if(a[i]>a[j+1])
            {
                int temp=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=a[i];
                a[i]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
}
```

and this is the output:

5
14
10
-1
-2

Comment: What did you find when you stepped through this code in your debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, you are comparing the element past the current index of `j`; you're always using `j+1`.  Stop adding 1 to `j` wherever you use it.  You're skipping the first element that way.

```
if(a[i] > a[j])
{
    int temp = a[j];
    a[j] = a[i];
    a[i] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bubble sort. You can find some explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) and [here](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/Bubble.htm).

```
public static void main(String args[]){

int[] vet = {8, 9, 3, 5, 1};
int aux = 0;
int i = 0;

System.out.println("Original Array: ");

for(i = 0; i<5; i++){
 System.out.println(" "+vet[i]);
}

System.out.println(" ");

for(i = 0; i<5; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j<4; j++){
          if(vet[j] > vet[j + 1]){
                aux = vet[j];
                vet[j] = vet[j+1];
                vet[j+1] = aux;
          }
      }
}

System.out.println("Ordered Array:");
    for(i = 0; i<5; i++){
          System.out.println(" "+vet[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gonna provide any sort of explanation?

Comment: Why don't you open your own question?

Comment: Because I don't need a question answered. It was more of a hint that pasting code and saying nothing about it is bad practice. Pasting code and links about it is barely better. You have made no attempt to explain specifically how this solves the OP's specific problem.